# Where are cellular data preferences stored in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, preferences, cellular-data

In Settings → Cellular (Mobile in UK), settings can be changed regarding mobile data, including per-app switches for all installed apps to enable or disable mobile data.

Where are these preferences stored?

I've looked in /var/mobile/Library/Preferences, but there doesn't seem to be any preferences relating to this. I've searched through the plists for various strings including app names and IDs from the list of per-app settings, but not found anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The directory you're looking for happens to be `/var/wireless/Library/Preferences`. This is where the `Settings > Cellular` settings are stored. The per-application settings are stored in the database `/var/wireless/Library/Databases/CellularUsage.db`. If you want to add a setting manually, you'll need to add an entry for the application in two tables. The first is `bundle_uuid`, and you'll need to set the `bundle_id` field to the friendly bundle name (such as `com.developersbliss.Helicopter`), and then the `macho_uuid` field to its UUID (such as `DD314675-0AA8-8A84-DB2BB966BAD8`) (Repeat this step for each UUID that the application has. In my particular example, there are two UUIDs. Just add another entry to the table for each UUID, but with the `bundle_id` set the same as before, and with the `macho_uuid` set to the next UUID the application has.). Then you'll need to make an entry in the `bundle_info` table with the `bundle_id` field set to the friendly bundle name used in the `bundle_uuid` table, and then the `flags` field set to `0`. This will make that particular application be restricted from using cellular data. To enable the application to use cellular data again, just set its `flags` field in the `bundle_info` table to `1`. Any application not found in this database is assumed to be allowed to use cellular data.