# Disable cellular data before using app

Tags: ios, cellular-data

The Cellular Data settings on my iPhone allow me to selectively switch off cellular data usage on a per-app basis. However, it seems I must consume data using that app before it shows up on the menu so I can disable it.

Is there a way to disable cellular data for new apps *before* those apps use any data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are cellular data preferences stored in iOS?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122837/where-are-cellular-data-preferences-stored-in-ios) — I know I said where, but the fantastic answer by Andrew does address the restricting data before the app is added to the database automatically.

Comment: @grgarside possibly but that other question is very developer-facing. A regular user, running a non-jailbroken device, can't access those files. This is strictly user-facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without jailbreaking, this currently isn't possible. You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this on the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

If you're jailbroken, I refer you to a fantastic answer that I received to one of my prior questions, which whilst isn't quite a duplicate per the comments above, can answer the question.

- [Where are cellular data preferences stored in iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122837/where-are-cellular-data-preferences-stored-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Like the guys said above, probably not without jailbreaking your device. Howver it might be worth trying to put your phone in airplane mode and then running the app.

It may just balk and say nope, sorry, gotta have a cellular connection it might try and then make that switch available, just guessing here but it's quick and simple, so why not.

The other option is a physical solution, EG a Faraday Cage.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage

Or if your prefer a metal box like one of those metal storage cabinets. The radio will be on but you'll have no coverage as the metal shield blocks the signals...

Comment: I actually thought Airplane Mode might help so I tried it with an app (official Twitter app) and unfortunately it doesn't show up in the apps-that-use-cellular-data list when you start it for the first time and the phone is in Airplane Mode. Pity, would have been an elegant solution.